# Python, networkx не рисует граф

Tags: python, networkx

По статье на сайте решил нарисовать простой граф с помощью networkX. Делал все по инструкции, но почему-то после выполнения кода ничего не происходит. Автор статьи, как и другие авторы, пишут, что визуализация происходит через matplotlib, но сами почему-то его импортируют, но не используют. В общем, по идее, после выполнения кода должен отрисоваться гарф из 3 ребер, но ничего не отрисовывается, привожу код ниже:

```
import itertools
import networkx as nx
import numpy.random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def add_nodes(nodes): # Упрощаем добавление вершин
    for i in nodes:
        graph.add_node(i)

def add_edge(f_item, s_item, graph):
    graph.add_edge(f_item, s_item)
    graph.add_edge(s_item, f_item) 


graph = nx.Graph()
add_nodes(('A','B','C'))

add_edge('A','B', graph)
add_edge('B','C', graph)


nx.draw_circular(graph,
         node_color='red',
         node_size=1000,
         with_labels=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто добавьте в конец строку:

```
plt.show()
```

[image: Результат]

**UPDATE.** *По просьбе в комментарии*

```
import itertools
import networkx as nx
import numpy.random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('img_avatar_3.png')


def add_nodes(nodes):  # Упрощаем добавление вершин
    for i in nodes:
        graph.add_node(i, image=img)


def add_edge(f_item, s_item, graph):
    graph.add_edge(f_item, s_item)
    graph.add_edge(s_item, f_item)


graph = nx.Graph()
add_nodes(('A', 'B', 'C'))

add_edge('A', 'B', graph)
add_edge('B', 'C', graph)

pos = nx.circular_layout(graph)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, pos, ax=ax)

plt.xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
plt.ylim(-1.5, 1.5)

trans = ax.transData.transform
trans2 = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform

piesize = 0.2  # this is the image size
p2 = piesize / 2.0
for n in graph:
    xx, yy = trans(pos[n])  # figure coordinates
    xa, ya = trans2((xx, yy))  # axes coordinates
    a = plt.axes([xa - p2, ya - p2, piesize, piesize])
    a.set_aspect('equal')
    a.imshow(graph.nodes[n]['image'])
    a.axis('off')
ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли.

Comment: Пожалуйста, это просто неочевидно, когда только начинаешь )

Comment: А Вы не знаете, можно ли в ребро графа добавить фотографию?) Просто я хочу соц. граф вк сообществ построить, было бы неплохо вместо просто круга поместить аватарку.

Comment: jupyter notebook и без этого показал результат...

Comment: @Интик, автор не использует jupyter, иначе и вопроса бы не возникло

Comment: @ЕвгенийБутолин обновил ответ по поводу картинки

Comment: @Serg Bocharov Спасибо, хотя у меня не сработало почему то. А если применить plt.imshow(img), то картинка помещается на фон, а все ребра графа перемещаются в одну точку. Ох и интересная библиотека)

Comment: Да я не весь код вставил, извините - исправил